# the right way of displaying an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So, I have this type of array

```
$fields = array('result'=>234, '1'=>1, '2'=>2, '3'=>4, ....'20'=>5);
```

and I have o display it in a table, but the 'result' key has to be the last column.
Until now I've used this approach, but the problem arrives as soon as i need to add other keys besides 'results', to the end of the table.

```
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
  if(strcmp('key', 'result') != 0)
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
  }
echo "<td>$fields['result']</td>";
```

I assume that is has to be a better approach. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is faster way:

```
$result = $fields['result'];
$otherResult = $fields['otherResult'];

unset($fields['result'], $fields['otherResult']);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
  echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}

echo '<td>' . $result . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $otherResult . '</td>';
```

You don't check key every time.

However if you really want - do it in following way:

```
if( $key == 'result' )
```

Comment: Where is the extra key OP requested at the end of the table?

Comment: Huh - I've noticed that @Jan-Henk has an identical answer. o0

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know the names of the keys you want to display at the end, so you can do something like the following:

```
$result = $fields['result'];
$otherResult = $fields ['other_result'];
unset($fields['result'], $fields['other_result']);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
}

echo "<td>$result</td>";
echo "<td>$otherResult</td>";
```

This is only useful to do for a small number of keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
// array of columns you want to add at the end of the table in sequence
// I used an array of columns and an exrta foreach loop to be able to support possible future more columns to be added
$last_cols = array('result'=>null, 'other'=>null);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    // check if current column is one of the cols to be added at the end
    if (in_array($key, array_keys($last_cols))) {
        $last_cols[$key] = $value;
        continue;
    }

    echo '<td>'.$fields['result'].'</td>';
}
// loop through last columns
foreach($last_cols as $col) {
    echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case your Datastructure is not well formed. Why dont you use

```
$result = 123;
```

? Or a simple object containing $result and $values like so:

```
class MyDataContainer {
   public $result = 0;
   public $values = array();
}
```

? I would recommend this, since it would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: If you have completely different types of values, they should be structured correctly. since array(1,2,3,4) is a list of numbers and array('result' => 999) is a single scalar result they should not be mixed in one structure in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first element the last element in an array (as you don't use the keys in your question):

```
$fields = array('result'=>234, '1'=>1, '2'=>2, '3'=>4, ....'20'=>5);

$fields[] = array_shift($fields);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/GuRqpCGP)